# account.cpp:4:38: error: no ‘void account::setBalance(double)’ member function declared in class ‘account’ void account::setBalance(double money)

Tags: c++

```
account.cpp:4:38: error: no ‘void account::setBalance(double)’ member function declared in class ‘account’
 void account::setBalance(double money)
```

I cannot figure out why I am getting this error. From what I can tell my member functions are clearly defined inside the account.h class. 
account.h

```
  1 #ifndef _ACCOUNT_H_
  2 #define _ACCOUNT_H_
  3 #include <string>
  4
  5 class account
  6 {
  7   private:
  8     double balance;
  9     std::string username;
 10    public:
 11     void setBalance(double);
 12     void setUsername(char[100]);
 13 };
 14
 15
 16 #endif
```

Here is my account.cpp

```
  1 #include "account.h"
  2 #include <string>
  3
  4 void account::setBalance(double money)
  5 {
  6   balance = balance + money;
  7 }
  8
  9 void account::setUsername(char userName[100])
 10 {
 11   username = userName;
 12 }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Are you sure it's finding the correct `account.h` file?

Comment: It works fine when I compile it with g++. What compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using g++ as well.

Comment: Put the full path to the header file and try.

Comment: It was accessing account.h.gch instead of account.h. Thank you.